# Probability that given weight is on the heavier side of a balance

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

Assume we have 6 balls weighting 101, 102, 103, 104, 105 and 106 in kg. If we randomly pick 3 balls and place them on one side of the scale and the other 3 left are placed on the other side of the scale. What is the probability that the ball weighting 106 kg is on the heavier side?

Comment: There are ${6 \choose 3}=10$ configurations, and we are aided by knowing if the 104 or 105 are with 106 then that side will always be heavier. It should now be easy to count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be the other two balls on the same side as the $106kg$ ball,

The event "106kg is on the heavier side"($E$) can be expressed as the following:

$$E \iff X+Y+106 \geq \left \lceil \frac{621}{2} \right\rceil = 311 \implies X+ Y \geq 311 - 106 = 205 \implies $$

$$P(E) = P(X + Y \geq 205)$$

If we set aside 106 then $X,Y$ are chosen from the remaining 5 balls, so there are ${5 \choose 2} = 10$ total possibilities. Of these, the ones that result in $205$ or higher are:

$(101,104),(101,105), (102,103), (102,104), (102,105), (103,104),(103,105),(104,105)$

So 8 possibilities out of 10, so $80\%$ probability that the side that htas 106 kg ball is the heavier side..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about the case where it is not guaranteed that there are 3 weights on each side(Assume at least one weight on each side)?

Comment: @fool_of_a_took you can solve in similar way for 106 being by itself and 106 being with one other, up through 4 others, these will be conditional probabilities: P(E|106 is part of a group of size i). You then add them up by multiplying P(106 is part of a group size i) with each conditional probability. For example, 106kg by itself will never be on the heaver side, similarly for being with only 1 other (given how all the weights are more or less 100 + y. On the flip size, if its in a group of 4 or 5 others it will always be on the heavier side, so really its just N=3 that matters.

Comment: Concretely -- P(E|N=i) = 0 if i is 1,2 and P(E|N=j) = 1 for j = 4,5 ,s so you just add up the probability it will be in a group of 4,5 + 0.8*probability being in group of 3

Answer (score 4):

The problem is same as considering the weights $1,2,3,4,5,6$ instead.

There are $\dfrac{6!}{3!3!2!}=10$ ways to divide $6$ distinct objects into two groups of threes. One way, quick enough, is to list out the ten pairs of triples and see for how many cases $6$ belongs to the group with larger sum.

A yet shorter way is to consider the sum $1+2+3+4+5+6=21$. $6$ belongs to heavier side, when sum of three weights including $6$ is more than $21/2=10.5$. Unfavorable cases are only two : $(6,1,2)$ and $(6,1,3)$.

Number of favorable events is $10-2=8$ and required probability is $8/10$.